# sed modifying in place with -i flag

Tags: sed, bioinformatics

I'm new to `GNU sed` (running on macOS) and wish to shorten some file headers (~50 K headers, 78.3 Mb).

I'm trying to modify FASTA files in place by specifying a backup extension with the `-i` flag.

So far I have

```
sed -i.bak 's/^([^|]+).[^|]+(.*)/\1\2/' file.fas
```

which should create a new file called `file.fas.bak`.

However, I'm getting the error

```
sed: 1: "s/^([^|]+).[^|]+(.*)/\1\2/": \1 not defined in the RE
```

Note `sed -re 's/^([^|]+).[^|]+(.*)/\1\2/' file.fas` prints correctly to screen.

Any ideas on how to print to a backup file in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the `-r` option, too, in order to enable interpretation of extended regular expression syntax (**but note** that `-E` is more portable than `-r` and [will soon supersede it](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528)), so you should use

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/^([^|]+).[^|]+(.*)/\1\2/' file.fas
```

Alternatively, resort to basic regular expressions:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\([^|]\{1,\}\).[^|]\{1,\}\(.*\)/\1\2/' file.fas
```

**Update**

In a reply to @terdon's question you confirmed that the files are FASTA files. In that case, you may improve efficiency by only considering header lines (those starting with `>`), as proposed by @terdon:

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/^(>[^|]+).[^|]+(.*)/\1\2/' file.fas
```

Comment: I'd expect those command lines to also work with macos' builtin `sed`. `-E` was added to BSDs first. GNU `sed` added `-E` as an alias to `-r` initially undocumented for compatibility with BSDs, and later documented when it appeared it was going to be specified by POSIX.